# iMac 2008 24" 3.06 ONLY starts in Windows SafeMode

Tags: macos, imac, windows, safe-mode

In Mavericks I get a reboot immediately on the grey screen after Verbose. Same in Safe mode with shift key down. 
Will start to Target screen. (but don't have a compatible computer to connect to)
Will run ASD from usb showing no errors other than Sound card on logic board which shows on most machines.
Wont run bootable OSX usb for Mavericks reinstall (well it did once, but crashed soon after. Disk util said no errors on that attempt. 
Will run Single user more where fsck -fy first run says modified then next run all ok. After next reboot modified again)
Wont start windows 7, crash when enter details at login screen.
WILL run Windows 7 Safe Mode stable! I've left running overnight and is fine.
Starts up Hirens boot cd but crashes on tests. Will run Linux and mini xp from cd.
Wont start up Diskwarrior from eDrive (external usb hard drive)

Any ideas how to get my iMac up and running? Its most odd that safe mode Win7 runs perfectly.

Thanks

Comment: This could potentially be an issue with your GPU. In my experience, the older iMac models are prone to GPU failure - especially in more humid environments. This would explain why safe mode works as no accelerated graphics drivers are loaded - also the same in single user mode.

Comment: @stan except it fails in macOS safe mode which uses software drivers instead of the gpu.  Suggest you run hardware diagnostics.